# Reledmac hide stanza numbering in text, keep in apparatus

Tags: line-numbering, reledmac

I've just started using reledmac to prepare a critical edition of a poem and I would like to number the stanzas automatically, hiding the stanza numbers on the left in the main text and keeping them in the apparatus. At the moment, I'm using this code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{reledmac}

\usepackage{amssymb}


\setlength{\stanzaindentbase}{20pt} 
\setstanzaindents{4,1,2,1,2,3,3,1,2,1}

\numberstanzatrue
\Xstanza
\Xstanzaseparator{.}
\begin{document}


\beginnumbering
\linenumberstyle{alph}
\renewcommand{\thestanza}{%
\arabic{stanza}%
}

\stanza 
\edtext{punaḥ skandhasthitaḥ}{\Afootnote{tataḥ skandhagatah G, Q illegible; 'yam mahān hi te Q.}{\Bfootnote{This is a trial.}}} prāha nirbandho 'yam aho nu te &  
bhuṅkṣva gatvā śriyam rājan no ced ekām kathām śṛṇu \&
\stanza 
śrīmān vetravatītīramekhalāyām mahābhujaḥ &
nagaryām vidiśākhyāyāṃ kṣmāpatiḥ śūdrako 'bhavat \& 
\stanza 
tasmai kadācid āsthāne caṇḍālapatiputrikā &
upāyanīkṛtam ratnaṃ dadau sarvavidaṃ śukam \&
\stanza 
rājñā kṛtaphalāhāraḥ sa pṛṣṭaḥ svakathām niśi &
ūce dīrghā 'sti veṇī 'va deva vidhyāṭavī bhuvaḥ \&
\endnumbering


\end{document}
```

I'm struggling to find a solution in the manual. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If you don't display the line numbers in the main text, doesn't that make it more difficult to know to which lines the footnotes correspond?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `\firstlinenum{100000}` to start line numbering at 100000. But as explained by Marijn, I don't think that is a good idea for final reader.

Comment: I understand what you both mean and obviously you're absolutely right. Actually, it's simply that the default numbering is on the left and at the beginning of each stanza and I'd prefer to have it on the right and at the end of each stanza, but I figured that this solution would be easier to implement and since it's verses I'll add the numbers manually at the end of each stanza.

Comment: you don't need to install it manually. You can set `\linenummargin{right}`  to have the line number on the right side. (what did you not ask for this question before?)

Comment: I tried what you suggest with `\linenummargin{right}`, but as I suspected it's not what I'd like to achieve. I have suppressed the _line_ numbers successfully, because I reference to stanzas in the apparatus. The _stanza_ numbers are then correctly displayed in the apparatus as well as on the left margin at the start of each stanza -- but I'd like them to be displayed on the right margin and at the end of each stanza, this is why I asked the first question. I still don't know how to change the position of the stanza numbering, but I guess I'll have to stick with the default.

Comment: hum, open a issue on reledmac github page. But, as precedely, why do you not expose your problem directly

Comment: Well, because after having read the manual, I figured that the solution to my issue would not have been straightforward and I thought instead of making you waste time with it, I supposed I could achieve the same result with a work-around. Apologies for wasting your time anyway.